# List manipulation for a Conditional Round-Robin Rugby Draw

Tags: python, list, algorithm, round-robin, sports-league-scheduling-problem

One of the Rugby Coaches at my school have asked me to code a conditional rugby match draw for the upcoming games with the task laid out something like this: Given a list of teams from 1 - 12 split into 3 groups ([Group1 = 1, 2, 3, 4], [Group2 = 5, 6, 7, 8,], [Group3 = 9, 10, 11, 12])
    generate and print an 11 round-robin matchup with the conditions that:

- Teams in Group1 does NOT verse teams in Group3
- Teams in Group1 verses every other team in Group 1 twice (Eg. 1v2, 2v1, 1v3, 3v1, 1v4, 4v1, 1v5, 5v1.....)

  This same rule applies to teams in Group3 as they verse other teams in Group3
- Teams in Group2 verse every other team once.
- Teams in Group1 and Group3 need one Bye Game.

I have attempted multiple times but inevitably become stuck, below are my 2 attempts:

Attempt 1:

```py
import operator
import functools
import random



###First Generation (Flawed unclean round robin)
def fixtures(teams):
    if len(teams) % 2:
        teams.append('Day off')  # if team number is odd - use 'day off' as fake team     

    rotation = list(teams)       # copy the list
    random.shuffle(rotation)

    fixtures = []
    for i in range(0, len(teams)-1):
        fixtures.append(rotation)
        rotation = [rotation[0]] + [rotation[-1]] + rotation[1:-1]

    return fixtures

def main():
    # demo code
    teams = ["Team1","Team2","Team3","Team4","Team5","Team6","Team7","Team8","Team9","Team10","Team11","Team12"]
    groupA = ["Team1","Team2","Team3","Team4"]
    groupB = ["Team5","Team6","Team7","Team8"]
    groupC = ["Team9","Team10","Team11","Team12"]

    # for one match each - use this block only
    matches = fixtures(teams)

    print("flawed matches:")
    RoundCounter = 0

    homeTeams = []
    awayTeams = []

    for f in matches:
        #print(f)
        homeTeams = f[::2]
        awayTeams = f[1::2]
        print("Home Teams:{}".format(homeTeams))
        print("Away Teams:{}".format(awayTeams))
        HomeTeamGroupA = set(homeTeams).intersection(groupA)
        HomeTeamGroupC = set(homeTeams).intersection(groupC)
        AwayTeamGroupA = set(awayTeams).intersection(groupA)
        AwayTeamGroupC = set(awayTeams).intersection(groupC)

        VSCounter = 0

        for p, o in zip(homeTeams, awayTeams):
            if p in HomeTeamGroupA:
                if o in AwayTeamGroupC:
                    AvsCPosition = awayTeams.index(o)
                    VSCounter += 1
                    RoundCleanUp(homeTeams, awayTeams, AvsCPosition, VSCounter) #if this is returned begin cleaning the round
                else: print("GroupA is versing either Group B or GroupA") #if this is returned it is a team 1-4 but is vs either group b or group a
            elif p in HomeTeamGroupC:
                if o in AwayTeamGroupA:
                    AvsCPosition = awayTeams.index(o)
                    VSCounter += 1
                    RoundCleanUp(homeTeams, awayTeams, AvsCPosition, VSCounter) #if this is returned begin cleaning the round
                else:
                    print("GroupC is versing either Group B or GroupC")  #if this is returned it is a team 9-12 but is vs either group b or group c
            else:
                pass

def RoundCleanUp(HTeam, ATeam, AvsCPos, VSCounter):
    ##gets Value of List at position
    HTeamVal = HTeam[AvsCPos]
    ATeamVal = ATeam[AvsCPos]
main()
```

Attempt 2:

```py
import operator
import functools
import random


def make_round(rotation, num_teams, fixtures):
    for i in range(num_teams - 1):
        rotation = list(range(1, num_teams + 1))
        # clip to 0 .. num_teams - 2 # if i == 0, no rotation is needed (and using -0 as list index will cause problems)
        i %= (num_teams - 1)
        if i:
            rotation = rotation[:1] + rotation[-i:] + rotation[1:-i]
        half = num_teams // 2
        fixtures.append(list(rotation[:half]))
        fixtures.append(list(rotation[half:][::-1]))
    return fixtures


def make_schedule(teams):
    """Produces RoundRobin"""
    # number of teams must be even
    TeamLength = len(teams)
    if TeamLength % 2:
        TeamLength += 1  # add a dummy team for padding

    # build first round-robin
    rotation = list(teams)
    Fixture = []
    schedule = make_round(rotation, TeamLength, Fixture)

    return schedule


def homeAwayRotation(matches):
    for homeTeams, awayTeams in zip(matches[0::2], matches[1::2]):
        print("Home Rotation: {}".format(homeTeams))
        print("Away Rotation: {}".format(awayTeams))
        validation(homeTeams, awayTeams)


def validation(homeTeams, awayTeams):
    groupA = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    groupC = [9, 10, 11, 12]


    for x, y in zip(homeTeams, awayTeams):
        if x in groupA:
            if y in groupC:
                AvsCPosition = awayTeams.index(y)
                cleanDirtyData(homeTeams, awayTeams, AvsCPosition)
            else:
                    # if this is returned it is a team 1-4 but is vs either group b or group a
                print("Group A vsing either itself or GroupB\n")
        elif x in groupC:
            if y in groupA:
                AvsCPosition = awayTeams.index(y)
                cleanDirtyData(homeTeams, awayTeams, AvsCPosition)
            else:
                # if this is returned it is a team 9-12 but is vs either group b or group c
                print("Group C vsing either itself or GroupB\n")
        else:
            # if this is returned it is a team in group B
            print("This is team B\n")


def cleanDirtyData(homeTeams, awayTeams, AvsCPosition):
    HTeamVal = homeTeams[AvsCPosition]
    ATeamVal = awayTeams[AvsCPosition]
    Dirtlist = []
    Dirtlist.append(HTeamVal)
    Dirtlist.append(ATeamVal)
def main():
    # demo code
    teams = ["Team1", "Team2", "Team3", "Team4", "Team5", "Team6",
             "Team7", "Team8", "Team9", "Team10", "Team11", "Team12"]

    # for one match each - use this block only
    matches = make_schedule(teams)

    print("flawed matches:")

    homeAwayRotation(matches)


main()
```

My expected results would be printing each round showing which team is versing which and each team having a history a bit like this:

- a team in Group1 has a verse history of: (in any random order)

  1v2, 2v1, 1v3, 3v1, 1v4, 4v1, 1v5, 1v6, 1v7, 1v8, bye
- a team in Group2 has a verse history of: (in any random order)

  5v1, 5v2, 5v3, 5v4, 5v6, 5v7, 5v8, 5v9 5v10, 5v11, 5v12
- a team in Group3 has a verse history of: (in any random order)

  9v10, 10v9, 9v11, 11v9, 9v12, 12v9, 9v5, 9v6, 9v7, 9v8, bye

Any pointers or improvements I could possibly do would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on the final hurdle for the last 2 weeks

Comment: Is it three groups of equal size? Also this is not really a round robin if not everyone plays vs everyone else

Comment: Is it correct that the teams `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` results in the matches: team 1: `[(1, 2), (2, 1), (1, 3), (1, 4), 'bye']`, team 2: `[(2, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), 'bye']`, team 3: `[(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 5), (3, 6)]`, team 4: `[(4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 5), (4, 6)]`, team 5: `[(5, 6), (6, 5), (5, 3), (5, 4), 'bye']`, team 6: `[(6, 5), (5, 6), (6, 3), (6, 4), 'bye']]` ?

Comment: for example, Team1 would have the match data of `[(1, 2), (2,1), (1, 3), (3,1), (1,4), (4,1), (1,5), (1,6), (1,7), (1,8), "bye" ]`

Team5 would verse against every team once

and Team9 would have a match history of `[(9, 10), (10,9), (9, 11), (11,9), (9,12), (12,9), (9,5), (9,6), (9,7), (9,8), "bye" ]`

one "bye" is required for each team in group1 and group3 to fit into an 11 round match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood the problem correct, then all you need is some combining of teams with every member in different groups.

I put some code together that should solve your problem:

```
def vs(team, group):
    matchups = map(lambda opponent: (team,opponent), group)
    matchups = filter(lambda tup: tup[0] != tup[1], matchups)
    return list(matchups)

def matches(teams):
    group_size = len(teams) // 3

    # Make the groups, basically just splitting the team list in three parts
    groups = [teams[:group_size], teams[group_size:2*group_size], teams[2*group_size:]]
    matchups = []
    for index, team in enumerate(teams):
        group_index = index // group_size
        current_matchup = []

        # Check if we're working with group 1 or 3
        if group_index == 0 or group_index == 2:

            # Flip the order of a tuple
            def flip(x):
                return (x[1], x[0])

            own_group = vs(team, groups[group_index])

            # Add matches against everyone in the group
            current_matchup.extend(own_group)

            # Add matches agains everyone in the group again, but now the current team is 'away'
            current_matchup.extend(list(map(flip, own_group)))

            # Add matches against everyone in group 2
            current_matchup.extend(vs(team, groups[1]))

            # Lastly, add the bye 
            current_matchup.append((team, "bye"))
        else:
            # Just all matches against all other teams, once.
            current_matchup.extend(vs(team, teams))
        matchups.append(current_matchup)
    return matchups

# This can be anything. Numbers, 'Team 1' or even 'The wondrous flying squirrels of death'
teams = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
# Make matches
matchups = matches(teams)


# Just pretty print
for i in range(len(matchups)):
    matches = '\n\t'.join(map(lambda m: f'{str(m[0]).rjust(10)} vs {str(m[1]).ljust(10)}', matchups[i]))
    print(f"Team '{teams[i]}' matches:\n\t{matches}")
```